# PS3 Wireless Connection on college campus

Tags: ps3

sorry if this is really simple, but I am trying to hook up my ps3 to my schools wireless network.  I have the SSID and the TKIP key.  When I test the connection, it finds an IP address and then fails the Internet connection.  I am not tech savvy at all, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any more information other than 'fails the internet connection'. Any error codes? Any other messages?

Comment: This might be something that you want to check with your schools IT Helpdesk instead of random people on the internet.  We have no idea about what's required for a machine to get access to the internet on your schools network.  There could be numerous restrictions on devices accessing the network, especially over WiFi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your campus require you to access a login page when you connect? If so, you'll have to use the PS3's browser to access it. After you do, you shouldn't have to log in every time you turn on the console.

Comment: Yup.  That was it...